# HTML layout in IE10 involving percentage width and height

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, height

An absolute positioned div in IE10 is not filling its parents height (works OK in latest Chrome and Firefox).

In the code below, the "percent-height" class is where the issue lies. It fills the width OK, but not the height.

If I set a pixel height (in cell 3), this is how I know the percentage "height" is the issue, not the width. I need a percentage height as this will be responsive.

Codepen for visuals: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNexOg

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
       <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="percent-height"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="px-height"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: grey;
}

.percent-height {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: green;
}

.px-height {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this Issue You can use the "display:flex" CSS where it will distribute the height dynamically.

```
.table{
   display: -ms-flex;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
}
.cell {
   -ms-flex: 1;
   -webkit-flex: 1;
   flex: 1;
}
```